# JMeter Debug Processor shows wrong information?

Tags: jmeter

As you can see on the herewith image, I'm trying to debug Http requests. So in order to do that I've attached an Listener and a debug post-processor.

The problem is that while my http request's response code is `401`, debug post-processor shows me an `200`!!

[image]

[image]

Moreover, in a `If Controller` I've written this condition: `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} == false`, and the code under it, is never reached!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Sampler Result tab you see the result related to Debug PostProcessor itself. I.e. in this case it tells you that Debug PostProcessor finished successfully with the Response code=200 and Size in bytes = 1516

Then on Request tab it will show you the configuration of the Debug PostProcessor.

Now if you look at the Response Data tab, this is where you see what Debug PostProcessor  actually returned. The thing is it has no ability to show the *result* of the parent sampler, only its configuration. So as a poster mentioned above, you cannot use it to look at result of the parent sampler. And frankly you don't need to, since you can see the result of any sampler by clicking on it in the View Results Tree, and selecting Sampler Result / Response Data.

Answer (score 3):

The Debug Sampler (and the Debug Post-Processor) doesn't do what I think you think it does.

It isn't debugging in the sense that you might be used to: it won't let you set a breakpoint and step by step through it. Instead, it gives you a list of all of the variables and their values in the "Response Data" tab. This lets you make sure that the variables that you're using are what you think they are.

Because that request- the Debug Request- succeeded, that's what's giving you the 200 response.

A 401 response makes it seem like your Access Tokens aren't being set correctly. I'd check the Debug Sampler and compare the Variables in there to what you're expecting.

Comment: Wow! It's really confusing. What's the difference between a Debug Post-Processor and a Debug Sampler then?

Comment: Just looking at them, I don't think there's much of a difference. JMeter has a couple Pre and Post Processors that have 'Sampler' counterparts. As far as I know, they all do the same thing. There is a bit of Functionality difference: if you put a Pre or Post Processor in a Controller (not under a specific Sampler), it will automatically execute on each Sampler in that Controller.